# Filling various missing categorical data in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I try to fill various missing categorical data in PySpark. I need to map all `000` and `null` to be 'UNDEFINED' but it turns converting all others data item to be `null`. Here's my Input

`lastvalue_month.select('province').show(50)`

```
+--------------------+
|            province|
+--------------------+
|         DKI JAKARTA|
|         DKI JAKARTA|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|              BANTEN|
|              BANTEN|
|                BALI|
|                BALI|
|                 000|
|         DKI JAKARTA|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|DAERAH ISTIMEWA Y...|
|                 000|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|      KEPULAUAN RIAU|
|      SUMATERA UTARA|
|      SUMATERA UTARA|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|              BANTEN|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|                 000|
|         DKI JAKARTA|
|              BANTEN|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|                 000|
|         DKI JAKARTA|
|         DKI JAKARTA|
|              BANTEN|
|         DKI JAKARTA|
|         DKI JAKARTA|
|         JAWA TENGAH|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|              BANTEN|
|         DKI JAKARTA|
|DAERAH ISTIMEWA Y...|
|              BANTEN|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|         DKI JAKARTA|
|         DKI JAKARTA|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|          JAWA BARAT|
|          JAWA TIMUR|
|         DKI JAKARTA|
+--------------------+
```

What I did

```
lastvalue_month = lastvalue_month.withColumn('province', when((col('province') == '000') | col('province').isNull(), lit('UNDEFINED')))
```

My output

```
+---------+
| province|
+---------+
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|UNDEFINED|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|UNDEFINED|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|UNDEFINED|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|UNDEFINED|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
+---------+
```

All filled data becoming `null`. What I need is all `000` and `null` to be 'UNDEFINED'. how to do this in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should also have an `otherwise` condition , to assign values that do not satisfy the `when` condition.

```
lastvalue_month.withColumn('province', when(
                            (col('province') == '000') | col('province').isNull(), lit('UNDEFINED')
                    ).otherwise(col('province')
                )
            )
```